# Dictionary value takes method type instead of property type

Tags: swift

I have a dictionary that can have `String` or `Int` values.
I remove the nil values with `compactMapValues`.

One of the String values is `capitalized` .

To sum it up, here's how my code looks :

```
let someOptional: Int? = nil

let test: [AnyHashable: Any] = [
    "Some optional" : someOptional,
    "Some capitalized string" : "\(true)".capitalized
].compactMapValues { $0 }
```

And when I access the second value :

```
test["Some capitalized string"]!
```

I get this : `(Function)` , instead of `True` .

I guess it's because `capitalized` is also a method and `Dictionary` probably takes the method type over the var type.

But why ? And how can I force it to take the `var` instead of the `func` ?

The only solution I found was to add `as String` after `capitalized`, but I find it weird that I need to do this..

Also the weird part is that if I remove the optional entry from the list, it works. Or if I replace the `"\(true)"` by `"true"` it works as well.

Comment: Remove `compactMapValues { $0 }` and it will work

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I can't, I have optional values. But thanks for answering

Comment: It doesn’t do anything anyway so you don’t need it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It does, it removes "Some optional" from the dictionary ?

Comment: It looks like it does, but it doesn't actually do anything. Print the values and see for yourself.

Comment: Oh wow thanks ! I need the compactMap to remove nil values, but indeed I'll remove the Any typing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could (but shouldn't) do this with a KeyPath subscript:

```
"Some capitalized string" : "\(true)"[keyPath: \.capitalized]
```

This avoids the possibility of considering the property to be a function itself. With this, the full solution that does what you want with `Any` looks like this:

```
let test: [AnyHashable: Any] = [
    "Some optional" : someOptional as Any,
    "Some capitalized string" : "\(true)"[keyPath: \.capitalized]
].compactMapValues { (value) -> Any? in
    switch value {
    case let int as Int?: return int
    default: return value
    }
}
```

The complicated `compactMapValues` is required because your current `compactMapValues` isn't actually doing anything:

```
print(test)
[AnyHashable("Some capitalized string"): (Function), 
 AnyHashable("Some optional"): nil]
```

Notice how "Some optional" is actually in the Dictionary? It's not filtered out as you probably expect, because its value is `.some(nil)`. The reasons for this are complicated (if you're interested, the problem is optional promotion coupled with the recursive nature of `Any?`). This whole approach is bad. It also generates a warning (Expression implicitly coerced from 'Int?' to 'Any'), which is why the `as Any` is required, even if `as String` can be avoided in this awkward way.

The weirdness is because you're trying to use Any as your type here. That's always going to lead to awkward type resolutions. It's even more awkward when you try to put Optionals in the Dictionary.

If your type is either a String or an Int, then use an enum for that.

My recommendation for inserting things conditionally is to keep it simple and just `if-let` it:

```
import Foundation

enum YourValue {
    // Use names here that match the meaning of these values.
    // "string" and "int" are here because you didn't tell us
    // what the values mean.
    case string(String)
    case int(Int)
}

let someOptional: Int? = nil

var test: [String: YourValue] = [
    "Some capitalized string" : .string("\(true != false)".capitalized)
]
if let someOptional {
    test["SomeOptional"] = .int(someOptional)
}
```

Alternately, you can still use your `compactMapValues` if it really helps you:

```
let test: [String: YourValue] = [
    "Some capitalized string" : .string("\(true != false)".capitalized),
    "SomeOptional": someOptional.map(YourValue.int)
].compactMapValues { $0 }
```

Don't use Any. You'll fight it constantly.

Comment: Oh wow I get it now, thanks a lot Rob ! I'll avoid Any as much as possible from now on